# Which are the different tex install loactions?

Tags: miktex, mac, mactex

I recently installed MikTeX but have had some problems with it some I've decided to change for MacTeX. However, I' kind of confused after checking the different locations of the executables. For example, running `where pdflatex` on my Terminal tells me it's located at `/Library/TeX/texbin/`, along others. When I used MikTeX, it installed the executables in the `~/bin/` directory. Now, I'd like to uninstall all latex related programs and executables for a clean install. I don't want `pdflatex`  and his friends installed in many different places in my computer.

**PS:** This is probably a duplicate question but I couldn't find any similar post so notify me if you do.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Can't you use the uninstall function provided by your OS?

Comment: Does MikTeX on Mac have an uninstall option? Note: /Library/TeX/texbin is really a symbolic link to a data structure installed by the MacTeX installer. You can have multiple years of TeX Live distributions on your system and TeX Live Utility (a GUI frront end for tlmgr installed by MacTeX) allws you to easily choose which distribution is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Not sure if this answers your question.
- MiKTeX has a [website](https://miktex.org/kb/texmf-roots) that lists the location for the root directories for different OSs.

[image]